# PHP echo of SQL query

Tags: php, sql, indexing, undefined, average

I've a problem with my code. I can't wrap my head around what's wrong with the code or where I fail.

I basically want to calculate the average of multiple numbers from my database from one column.

```
/*data calculation*/
$calculation = "SELECT AVG(current) FROM offset_items";
$calculation_result = mysqli_query($connect, $calculation);

if($average = mysqli_fetch_assoc($calculation_result))
    {echo "Average: ".$average["current"]."<br>";}
```

The problem here is, that I get only a blank displayed after the "Average: ".
But if I remove the AVG from the query, I get all results listed of that DB column. The DB contains data, which I import in the same script, as well as displaying them for testing.

I get the following error, which is the line of the echo:

```
Notice: Undefined index: current in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Offset_Items.php on line 50
```

I think the problem here is the mysqli_fetch_assoc, but I'm not sure.
Digging through the multiple topics about that "Undefined index" didn't solve my problem. Even when I declare the variable before as NULL.

I'm out of touch with programming, but currently picked it up again to code some tools for work. So if you guys could help me, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Can you please share the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP code that attempts to print the result reads:

```
$average = mysqli_fetch_assoc($calculation_result);
echo "Average: ".$average["current"]."<br>";
```

but the query that generates the result set does not contain any column named `current`.

Use an [alias](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for the expression `AVG(current)` in the `SELECT` clause to get a column in the result set having the desired name:

```
SELECT AVG(current) AS current FROM offset_items
```